# Explain this class file having code for SQLite + C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm posting here the code for a project made for SQLite connection by C#.
I've tried to understand but not satisfied.

What i think of this code does is:

- create a Table in Database named `Contact`
- this table 'll have attributes as mentioned in the Contact Class file ID, First Name, Last Nam & e-mail.
- and the implementation of `ToString()` method will return a string having the First name and Last name of the entered user.

Though someone please help me with the proper explanation.

Here we go...

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using SQLite;

namespace VSMWin8SqliteDemo.DataAccess.Entities
{
    [Table("Contacts")]
    public class Contact
    {
        [PrimaryKey, Unique, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0}, {1}", LastName, FirstName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read up about EF CodeFirst, ComponentModel Attributes

Comment: I'll be more glad if you could provide me with some of the help-full link for that, if possible

Comment: [Entity Framework Code First](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/03/30/data-annotations-in-the-entity-framework-and-code-first.aspx) This stuff has nothing to do with Sqlite. EF abstracts away Sqlite.

Comment: works fine on me. Just google "Entity Framework Code first data annotations"

Comment: @Aron -- seems MSDN is down for some people (me)

Comment: I got it.
@Aron: thanx buddy...
actually i found for sqlite, so i think it's for sqlite only.

Answer (score 0):

When table is generated by code first it should produce something like this [image: screenshot]